Anyway to get more description about wav files?
well i have a faster-whisper model and two files: when i put the first one into the model it returns me nonsense subtitles, BUT then i put the second file into model it work perfect
import wave

file_path = './BAD_FILE.wav'
with wave.open(file_path, 'rb') as wf:
    channels = wf.getnchannels()
    samplerate = wf.getframerate()
    samplewidth = wf.getsampwidth()
    nframes = wf.getnframes()

    print(f"Channels: {channels}")
    print(f"Sample Rate: {samplerate}")
    print(f"Sample Width: {samplewidth} bytes")
    print(f"Number of Frames: {nframes}")
    print(f"Duration: {nframes / samplerate:.2f} seconds")
    
file_path = './GOOD_FILE.wav'
with wave.open(file_path, 'rb') as wf:
    channels = wf.getnchannels()
    samplerate = wf.getframerate()
    samplewidth = wf.getsampwidth()
    nframes = wf.getnframes()

    print(f"Channels: {channels}")
    print(f"Sample Rate: {samplerate}")
    print(f"Sample Width: {samplewidth} bytes")
    print(f"Number of Frames: {nframes}")
    print(f"Duration: {nframes / samplerate:.2f} seconds")


this code gains me output
(bad file output)
Channels: 1
Sample Rate: 48000
Sample Width: 2 bytes
Number of Frames: 480000
Duration: 10.00 seconds

(good file output)
Channels: 1
Sample Rate: 11025
Sample Width: 2 bytes
Number of Frames: 390735
Duration: 35.44 seconds

is there any other information that affects model's results? because i dont think that sample rate has so huge effect

Why do you think that's garbage?  48kHz mono 16-bit PCM seems like a perfectly valid format.  If it's doing speech recognition, perhaps it just can't be recognized.  WAV files are not complicated.  There's a header that describes the format, then just a huge chunk of samples.  And the sample rate has a HUGE effect -- if the recognizer doesn't have the correct sample rate, then of course it will read nonsense.

do you have the same audio in both files? Maybe take good file, convert to sample rate like in bad file and check if it will still give good result.

Found a solution. Model target sample rate was 16000 (there is no docs about it), so audios with sample rate 16000+ (48k in my case) cant be recognized properly.
